# External and internal redirection using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert http://mywebsite.com/folder/file.html to http://mywebsite.com/file. 
I am not using regular expression as first I am only concerned about this one URL only.

I tried this-

```
Redirect 301 /folder/file.html http://mywebsite.com/file
```

Using this I am able to externally redirect this URL to the desired one but since the URL doesn't exist so I am getting 404.

Now, in order to internally redirect the new URL to the old one, I am using below command but it doesn't seem to work-

```
RewriteRule http://mywebsite.com/file http://mywebsite.com/folder/file.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `mod_rewrite` directives and use `THE_REQUEST` variable for external redirection.

```
# turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/folder/file\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /file [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^file/?$ /folder/file.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Anubhava, right now if am hitting the new shorter URL then the page is loading successfully. 
But on hitting the old URL there is no redirection to the shorter URL although the page is loading fine.

Comment: URL - http://artoftesting.com/manualTesting/beta-testing.html
.htaccess entry for external redirection-
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/manualTesting/beta-testing\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /beta-testing [R=301,L,NE]

Comment: You had one extra `/` in your rule. Try my updated rules now.

Comment: Thanks Anubhav, its working now. Please update your answer to the previous edit so, that it answers the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156663/discussion-between-kuldeep-rana-and-anubhava).